# Extract object to a dataframe from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to automatise a process in R with a loop. What I am trying to do is make R to read each data frame, insert it into a list so i can call it later.

```
datalist <- list(length = 4)

datalist[[1]] <- read.csv("df1.csv", sep=',', header=F)
datalist[[2]] <- read.csv("df2.csv", sep=',', header=F)
datalist[[3]] <- read.csv("df3.csv", sep=',', header=F)
datalist[[4]] <- read.csv("df4.csv", sep=',', header=F)
```

This works perfectly fine, but then when I am trying to use it in the for loop it says I cannot take an element to a list and make a dataframe,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(datalist)) {
  
  inputdata <- data[[i]]

}
```

The error that returns is `Error in data[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

The data frames are quite simple, i will show you the `head` of one individual in case it helps, it is a value and different columns stating different conditions, although I don't believe this is something relevant in this case.

```
> head(df)
       V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 0.40955  1  1  1  1  1
2 0.55674  1  1  1  2  1
3 0.53575  1  1  1  3  1
4 0.36518  1  2  1  1  1
5 0.49821  1  2  1  2  1
6 0.61912  1  2  1  3  1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. A list has no rows, only a `length`. Use `i in seq_along(datalist)`. 2. You don't create an object `data`. Thus, R tries to subset the inbuilt function `data`, which causes the error.

Comment: Your list is called `datalist` while you are trying to subset `data`. However, as `data()` is also the name base R function you get the famous `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` error message.

Comment: True, I have an object with different vectors, which represent different columns. Any idea on how to convert them into a dataframe?

Comment: You are right @stefan, I've just realised this was indeed a silly question. Thanks and my apologies!!

Comment: You do not have vectors. `read.csv` returns data.frames. Perhaps you actually want `do.call(rbind, datalist)` or `do.call(cbind, datalist)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your loop:

Firstly, `nrow(datalist)` is `NULL` so your loop isn't looping through each item in your list. You should just `length(datalist)` instead:

```
> nrow(datalist)
NULL
> length(datalist)
[1] 4
```

Secondly, as mentioned in the comments you're using `data` not `datalist`. The following will work for you:

```
for (i in 1:length(datalist)) {
  inputdata <- datalist[[i]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ```nrow``` and ```length``` input too!

Answer (score 1):

your loop should be as follow:

```
input_list <- c("df1.csv", "df2.csv", "df3.csv", "df4.csv")
datalist <- lapply(input_list, read.csv, sep=',', header=F)
```

---

The problem with your loop is that `data` is a function in R.

Therefore if you use `data` without creating an object call `data`, R will think you're calling that function.

If you want to use create a `for` loop that reads each input you should try this way:

```
input_list <- c("df1.csv", "df2.csv", "df3.csv", "df4.csv")
datalist <- list(length = length(input_list))


for (i in seq_along(input_list){
  datalist[i] <- read.csv(input_list[i], sep=',', header=F)
}
```

The solution with `lapply` is however more elegant and usually preferred over this one.

Comment: This is in fact very useful too. Thanks for the insight, @stefan realised I was mixing names though. Thanks everyone!